# how can I use rangeselector and navigation in highcharts in the given code

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        chart: {renderTo: 'container', type: 'line',}, rangeSelector: {enabled: true}, series: [{}]
    };
    $.getJSON('chart.php', function (data) {
        options.series[0].data = data
        var chart = new Highcharts.chart(options);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The range selector and navigator are Highstock features. To use them, use Highstock source code and `stockChart` constructor type.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: true
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('chart.php', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data
        var chart = new Highcharts.stockChart(options);
    });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n49t268u/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/understanding-highstock

Comment: Hi @Sahil Mantoo, As you can see, in the example that I have provided the range selector and navigator work. Please provide me with a live example where your problem occurs.